# A program that prints the following pattern

Tags: java

I have to code a program to print this output:

```
                                   1
                                  212
                                 32123
                                4321234
                               543212345
```

I have successfully coded this portion of the pattern:

```
                                   1
                                   12
                                   123
                                   1234
                                   12345
```

However, I am not reaching the second portion. Here's my code:

```
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    for(int j=1; j<=i; j++) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }
System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should try printing the half you want/need in other piece of code, then think about mix both.

Comment: The code looks like a triangle!

Comment: You may find this CodeGolf question nice: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8696/print-this-diamond

Answer (score 1):

Why not recursive? Just because it's fun ;)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(pyramid(5));
}

public static String pyramid(int rank) {
    if (rank == 1) {
        return "1\n";
    }
    return pyramid(rank - 1) + mirror(rank) + "\n";
}

public static String mirror(int rank) {
    if (rank == 1) {
        return "1";
    } else {
        return rank + mirror(rank - 1) + rank;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's fun; however, I'm a novice :P

Answer (score 0):

You just need another `j` `for` loop before your current `j` `for` loop that counts down from `5` to (but not including) `1`.  Decide whether to print a space or `j` itself, depending on if `j` is greater than `i`.

```
for (int j=5; j > 1; j--) {
    if (j > i)
       System.out.print(' ');
    else
       System.out.print(j);
}
```

Comment: Is there any code other than decrementing and without using the if/else statement?

Answer (score 0):

As someone already noted, you can accomplish this easily with a double for-loop, one counting down from i, one counting up:

```
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {

        for(int j=i; j>=2; j--) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        for(int j=1; j<=i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

You can also accomplish the same thing in a single for loop if you don't print right away. For example you can build an StringBuffer with one, then add the numbers on either side until i==j, and then print outside of the inner loop.

```
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        buffer.append(1);
        for(int j=2; j<=i; j++) {
           buffer.insert(0, j);
           buffer.append(j);
         }
        System.out.println(buffer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package recAaA;

public class testA {

    static void rec(int startVal, int endVal)
    {
        if(startVal==0)startVal=-2;
        if(startVal<-endVal) return;
        System.out.print(Math.abs(startVal));
        rec(startVal-1,endVal);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int imax=5;
        for(int i=1;i<imax+1;i++)
            {
                  for(int j=0;j<imax+1-i;j++)
                  {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                  }
                  rec(i,i);
                  System.out.println();
             }
    }


}
```

Output:

```
     1
    212
   32123
  4321234
 543212345
```

if you give i to startVal and i+1 to endVal, the output becomes

```
     12
    2123
   321234
  43212345
 5432123456
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that outputs the numbers; all you have to do is fix the spacing.

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        BigInteger b =
            BigInteger.TEN.pow(2*i-1)
            .subtract(BigInteger.ONE)
            .divide(BigInteger.valueOf(9))
            .multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i+1))
            .subtract(BigInteger.TEN.pow(i)
                      .subtract(BigInteger.ONE)
                      .divide(BigInteger.valueOf(9))
                      .pow(2));
        System.out.println(b);
    }
```

That is, for each integer in the range 1-9, it prints ((10<sup>2n-1</sup>-1)/9)(n+1)-((10<sup>n</sup>-1)/9)<sup>2</sup>.  Very simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Basically logic is that in a horizontal line upto the mid ,the number is decrementing and after the mid, the number starts incrementing 
*/


public class java {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int n;
        InputStreamReader io = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(io);
        System.out.println("Enter the height in the number of lines vertically");
        n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            int k = i;

            for (int j = 1; j <= 2 * i - 1; j++) {
               System.out.print(k);
                if (j >= (((2 * i - 1) / 2) + 1))
                    k++;  
                 else if(j<(2*i-1)/2+1) k--;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this will help !

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   int i,j,k,l,n,a;
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   n = sc.nextInt();
   a = n;
   for(i=1 ; i<=n ; i++){
      for(j=a ; j>1 ; j--){
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      for(k=i ; k!=0; k--){
        System.out.print(k);
      }
      a--;
      for(l=2; l<=i ; l++){
        System.out.print(l);
      }
      System.out.println(" ");
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int i=1;i<=100; i++) {
        for(int j=100;j>i;j--)
            System.out.print("  "); 

        for(int k=i;k>1;k--)
        System.out.print(k+" ");            
        for(int j=1; j<=i; j++) 
            System.out.print(j+" ");

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter no ");
        int n=in.nextInt();

        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            int l=n-i;
            while(l!=0)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
                l--;
            }
            for(int j=i;j>=2;j--)
            {
                System.out.print(j);

            }

            for(int k=1;k<=i;k++)
            {


                System.out.print(k);

            }


            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hope you got your desired pattern